# How to get list of Azure container files?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

I'm working on PS script to list all Storage Accounts, which contains files with a modified date less than **< X**.

I'm able to list all SA containers, it's not a big deal but I'm not sure how to get further and **list all files inside a particular container**.

```
$storageAccCtx = (Get-AzStorageAccount -Name acc_name -ResourceGroupName acc_rg).Context

Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccCtx
```

I couldn't find any cmdlet for this.

Could anyone, please, advise what should I use next? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-AzStorageBlob` to list the blobs in a storage container, the cmdlet is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-3.8.0).  In a script you could use this cmdlet as follows to return all the blobs older than a particular date:

```
$CutOffDate = Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 10 -Day 19
$OldBlobs = @()
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
foreach ($StorageAccount in $StorageAccounts) {
    $Containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $StorageAccount.Context
    foreach ($Container in $Containers) {
        $ContainerBlobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container.Name -Context $StorageAccount.Context
        $OldBlobs += $ContainerBlobs | Where-Object { $_.LastModified -lt $CutOffDate }
    }
}
$OldBlobs
```

Comment: Looks very promising, thank you for such complete and informative answer. Will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Why do we need to remove a variable in every iteration, we are calling for a new one each time with the $ContainerBlobs, don't we?

Comment: That was to ensure that if Get-AzStorageBlob returned null that the variable didn't hold onto it's previous value which would end up reporting duplicate results.  I've just tested that and it's unnecessary so I've removed that line

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the StorageContext, you can use this below Azure Storage Management Cmdlet to list all BlockBlob.

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container containerName -Context $storageAccCtx
```

To get list of all Azure Storage Management Cmdlet, please follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-4.8.0

Comment: Thank you very much, will check it out.